# Input using session values in the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP form for payment like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <h2>Payment Gateway Testing Sample</h2>
  <h3>Fill the form and submit it for starting the transaction...</h3>
 </div>

<div>
<table>
 <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>firstname</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>productinfo</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="success.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="fail.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
 </form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user logs in and visits this page, the data should be automatically added in the form using session. How can i do this?

Comment: Do you mean `session storage`?

Comment: use session/post to prefill the page

Comment: yes. something like storing the values in session and then inputing it to the for fields

Comment: Let's make it clear, do you mean PHP `$_SESSION` at server, or `sessionStorage` on users browser?

Comment: What have you stored in session while user logged in? I mean it could be id our username. I will answer according to this.

Comment: Save user info into session when user login into website.

Comment: i have stored something like this $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;

Comment: Then what prevents you to add the data similary you've already echoed `$txnid` in your code?

Comment: i dont know how to input these values in the form

Comment: Then you've to define "_the data_". Though there's an echo in the code already setting a value of an input, just apply the same method with other inputs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer is for PHP Session. We can access all the Session value using $_SESSION. link [PHP: $_SESSION - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)  . but first you need to store data in $_SESSION (session).

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Payment Gateway Testing Sample</h2>
        <h3>Fill the form and submit it for starting the transaction...</h3>
    </div>

<div>
<table>
    <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['amount']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>firstname</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>productinfo</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['productinfo']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="success.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="fail.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks mate. can you tell me one more thing. my amount is not comming from session. its comming from my html page. like there are 3 plans $500,$300 and $600. how can this value be automaticaly inserted

Comment: Welcome @king khan. Can you tell me how actually amount is passes here. By POST or GET method.

Comment: i havent assigned that. in an html page there are three options which i gave in a div. and 3 paynow buttom for each of them. all the three buttons redirects to this payment page.

Comment: ok after click button do you pass any parameter in url ? like . payment.php?amount=5000 (parameter passing through url in case of payment is bad idea i think.)

Comment: the buttons are like this <form action="payu.php" method="get">
      <input type="submit"  value="pay now">
</form>

Comment: <form action="payu.php?amount=5000" method="get"> <input type="submit" value="pay now"> </form>. you can access those amount  b using **$_GET['amount']**. <input type='text' value="**<?php echo $_GET['amount']; ?>**">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172393/discussion-between-thatal-and-king-khan).